# Instrumentation test fails when run in headless emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, integration-testing, headless

I'm using an Android 7.1.1 x86_64 emulator and the test passes when run in UI mode but fails when it is run in headless mode. Can anyone please help me?

This is the command I used to create avd

```
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;default;x86_64"
```

command to run emulator in headless mode

```
emulator -avd test -skin 540x960 -no-window -no-audio -no-snapshot
```

command to run test

```
gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest --stacktrace
```

And this is the error i get

```
Tests on test(AVD) - 7.1.1 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
```